# hadoop start-dfs having issues

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to install hadoop 2.8.1 on a windows 2012 server, I formatted the namenode already using command: hdfs namenode -format, and worked, I go to use start-dfs to get hdfs going, however I get this error message:

```
17/10/26 12:42:53 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.a
ccess0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)

  at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:6
 06)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:958)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkAccessByFileMethods(DiskCheck
er.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirAccess(DiskChecker.java:19
0)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode$DataNodeDiskChecker.c
heckDir(DataNode.java:2572)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.checkStorageLocations
(DataNode.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode
.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(D
 ataNode.java:2489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNo
de.java:2536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2721)
```

Comment: Refer to the solution posted in the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100930/unable-to-start-namenode-and-datanode-in-hadoop-2-8-0-rc1-error-java-lang-uns and Give a try !

Comment: I did try, exactly and still didn't work, i also already had a lib directory, not sure if he did or not. sadly still having the same issue.

Comment: thank you for that it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100930/unable-to-start-namenode-and-datanode-in-hadoop-2-8-0-rc1-error-java-lang-uns solution.